# How to change input type time that is bind in Blazor

Tags: html, asp.net-core, blazor, asp.net-blazor

I need to edit datetime value that is on the HTML table. I got the table data as a string then convert to Datetime and get the value in a time field of Html I mean `<input type="time" >`. I can get the value but I cannot edit from the HTML. Here is my code:

```
 <input type="time" style="width:100%"   @bind="@my_DateTime" />
```

Here is my model class. Note that I got the data as a string then convert it as a Datetime.

```
 private DateTime? _my_DateTime;
    [Parameter]
    public DateTime? my_DateTime
    {
        get
        {
            if (mytimestring != "")   //This is String I got data 
            {
                _my_DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(mytimestring);
                return _my_DateTime ;
            }
            else
            {
                _my_DateTime  = null;
                return _my_DateTime ;
            }
        }
        set
        {
           

            
            _my_DateTime = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("my_DateTime");
            //}
            //  NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => 並び順);
        }
    }
```

This is the string property I got from table:

```
 private string _mytimestring;
    [Parameter]
    public string mytimestring 
    {
        get
        {
            return _mytimestring ;
        }
        set
        {
            _mytimestring  = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(mytimestring");
            //  NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => 並び順);
        }
    }
```

Note I bind value to textbox like `<input type="text" @bind="@名称Str" />` and it works but only Datetime I cause issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is one of the things that have changed after a lot of advice was already on the internet.  I found that the binding works perfectly without any parsing or formatting.

I was also very surprised to see that when you bind an html `time` input to a C# `DateTime`, it will actually fill in today's time and date automatically.  (Not needed for your question, but a very interesting thing to know I think)

The following worked fine for me.

```
@page "/time"

<input type="time" @bind="@SomeTime" />
<br />
@SomeTime.ToString("hh:mm tt")
<br />
@SomeTime.ToString()

@code {
    public DateTime SomeTime = new DateTime();
}
```